# How should I set up my rear shock (with ProPedal) to minimise bob when climbing?

Tags: mountain-bike, full-suspension

I've got a Fox RP23 rear shock which I'm very happy with, apart from the apparent ineffectiveness of the ProPedal setting.  Bob is very noticeable on climbs in both positions.  It's hard to say which is better.  I don't expect to eliminate it completely, I just want to know that I've got the optimal setup for my bike and riding style. [The manual](http://www.foxracingshox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/07/eng/rear_shocks/float_rp23.htm#ProPedal) is pretty vague so I'm wondering if anyone has any useful tips?

Comment: I get the impression from the manual that they're vague about what setting to use because that's the point of an adjustable shock. The key bit is "To determine which ProPedal position is better for your condition and situation, pedal the bicycle and monitor the shock movement". I suggest trying each of the three settings on separate attempts at a climb you know reasonably well. Time your climbs and you should get some idea. If the answer is "they're all the same" you're not getting any benefit from the adjustability.

Comment: What bike do you have?  Some designs before from pro-pedal more than others.

Comment: @moz Timing a climb is a good idea.  I suppose as long as I use the same gear each time it would be a reasonably equal test.  @sillyyak The bike is an '08 Rocky Mountain Element 30.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but you said "both positions" right?  As I understand it, there are 3 propedal levels that you adjust by pulling out the knob and aligning the number with the lever.  Flipping the lever back and forth turns propedal on and off.  If "1" is pointing at lever, the propedal will be very minimal.

Comment: @sillyyak Well yes you would think that but I don't know what each level actually means and as I said the manual is vague, e.g. 'switch positions and select a setting that reduces suspension movement most effectively'.  It doesn't even commit to whether propedal being on or off will reduce movement more.

Comment: On, for what it's worth. It's also common for the internal valving on these shocks to bleed, which may mean there actually is no difference between settings.

Answer (score 1):

Pro-Pedal provides bob resistance when on, 1 being lowest.

Try this.  Pull out the numbered knob and position it so that "3" is in line with lever.  That will give you the most Pro-Pedal.  Now, try riding up a hill with it off and again with it on.  You should notice markedly less bob with it on.  If not, I might take it to a shop to make sure that it is working.

Comment: Yes I will try this, also moz's suggestion to time myself in each setting.

Comment: Hey z7sg, did you get a chance to see if it worked?

Comment: No I've only been out on the road bike.  Rest assured I shall return with the data soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same shock on my xc bike and I find the pro pedal very plush even on firm. I'm a big guy (~220 lbs) and run the shock somewhere around 150 psi so your scenario may be different. I always climb with the rear locked, ride flat terrain with the pro pedal on @ the firmest setting (3) and flip to full travel for any downhill. You will always have the most efficient climbing with the shock locked out; you rarely need rear suspension on the uphills anyways...